# Can I pass html elements into a jinja variable?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, jinja2

I am trying to set up a way to automatically format an input field to use the currency function of python's locale module.  However, I am running into an issue passing references into segment of jinja.

If I hardcode the value of the input like this it gives me my correctly formatted value:

```
<input onkeyup="this.value='{{ currency(20)) }}'>
```

However, what I really need is instead of passing in 20, I want it to use user input, therefore I need to pass in the current value of the input field itself.

I tried something like :

```
<input onkeyup="this.value='{{ currency(this.value())) }}'>
```

I have also tried using document.getElementbyId and a number of other variations, problem is that none of those objects are available inside of the {{ }}.  Anyone have any sugestions, is jinja capable of doing this type of dynamic processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible because Jinja creates the HTML before the page is sent to the client and any Javascript runs.

The only way to do this dynamically in serverside Python would be via an AJAX call which would be very inefficient.

My suggestion is you find an implementation of the currency formatting function in Javascript. A quick google on this should give you lots of options.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of why it doesn't work.  Makes sense, will have to go with one of the pure JS or jquery options.  I had very much wanted to use the python library for this though.

Comment: how do we get access them with ajax?